# Pass Gridview one Row TextBox value To Another Row Textbox Value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Gridview with 10 Rows each row have 2 columns which is Textbox and Checkbox.

what i have to do is  have to enter textbox Value as 1000 and  i Clicked the Checkbox at first Row then value must go to Textbox of Second row and i clicked checkbox of Second Row then value must be go to third row of Textbox  and so on.

i tried  this,

```
protected void txtintroId_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
        GridViewRow grid = ((GridViewRow)txt.Parent.Parent.Parent);
        TextBox txtIntro = (TextBox)txt.FindControl("txtintroId");
  }
```

here i get the 1st row Value but How do i pass this to second Row.

Assist me

Comment: rows are fixed? 10 ?

Comment: it may change upto 50

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: i got the 1st Textbox Value by Checkbox_changedEvent but How do i Pass that Value in to Second Row ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is full working code(as per your requirement )

1. Create a gridview like this

`<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">

           <Columns>

              <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("txtcolumn") %>'></asp:TextBox>
              </ItemTemplate>

              </asp:TemplateField> 
              <asp:TemplateField>

              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox2_CheckedChanged"  />
              </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
           </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>`

2. Add a function in code behind C#

   `protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
       int rowNo=0;
       foreach (GridViewRow GV1 in GridView1.Rows)
       {
       rowNo++;//`
       `if (rowNo < GridView1.Rows.Count) //Checking that is this last row or not
       {

           //if no
       CheckBox chkbx= (CheckBox)GV1.FindControl("CheckBox1");
       TextBox curenttxtbx = (TextBox)GV1.FindControl("TextBox1");
       if (chkbx.Checked == true )`
       `{

   ```
           int nextIndex = GV1.RowIndex + 1;//Next row
           TextBox txtbx = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[nextIndex].FindControl("TextBox1");
           txtbx.Text = curenttxtbx.Text;

       }

   }
       //if yes
   else
   {
       //For last row
       //There is no next row
   }
   ```

   }
   }
3. And i used this data table as data source

   DataTable table = new DataTable();
       table.Columns.Add("txtcolumn", typeof(string));

   ```
   table.Rows.Add("1");
   table.Rows.Add("32");
   table.Rows.Add("32");
   table.Rows.Add("32");
   table.Rows.Add("3");
   table.Rows.Add("32");
   table.Rows.Add("32");
   ```

I tested this code it is working as per your requirement. (And SORRY for this bad formatting. i will do it later or please some body correct the formating :))

Comment: thank you for your effort.i just did by using Session. how about that ? :))

Comment: this approach is very clean and  will take very less memory usage in compare to session.  By using session is not a good idea!! you will waste  memory of server.

Comment: You can check the code if you like then it's ok if not then also OK :)